# pandas change e notation to 10 exponent representation

Tags: python, pandas

I have pandas dataframe which has numerical value xxxxe-n like this:

```
    Feature         p-value
0   FuzzYEn11       1.915683e-19
1   DimFractal11    2.352654e-18
2   Approx11        2.960694e-15
3   SampEnt11       2.249975e-19
4   D211            7.058137e-17
... ...             ...
145 FuzzYEn416      6.374531e-04
146 DimFractal416   2.476636e-18
147 Approx416       2.708140e-05
148 SampEnt416      4.232942e-02
149 D2416           3.184591e-08
```

Since i want to make a report about this result, due efficiency reason i want all p-value set to 2-decimal round following with 10 exponent just like this:

```
149 D2416           3.18x10-8
```

Is there anyway to do this with pandas directly without i edit it manually in word or excel? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `map` with `format` and `replace` to get the output you want

```
df['p-value'] = df['p-value'].map('{:0.2e}'.format).replace("e", "*10^",regex=True)
```